# Left joining two tables, multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I need to left join two tables: `Cardealers` and `Applications`.

I want to see which cardealers have received which applications.

Each application is forwarded to three cardealers thus my table structure is having these 3 columns: `receiver_1`, `receiver_2`, `receiver_3`.

Where the ID in the receiver columns is the same as the `cardealer_id`.

I have this code functioning for ONE and one column only:

```
$res1 = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT leads.*, cardealers.*
    FROM leads
    LEFT JOIN cardealers ON leads.receiver_1 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    WHERE leads.receiver_1 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    AND cardealers.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."'" );

$res2 = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT leads.*, cardealers.*
    FROM leads
    LEFT JOIN cardealers ON leads.receiver_2 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    WHERE leads.receiver_2 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    AND cardealers.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."'" ); 

$res3 = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT leads.*, cardealers.*
    FROM leads
    LEFT JOIN cardealers ON leads.receiver_3 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    WHERE leads.receiver_3 = cardealers.cardealer_id
    AND cardealers.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."'" );
```

As you can see I do 3 separate statements which all works. But I want to combine these into one statement.

How do I do this?

Comment: See normalisation. Any time you have enumerated columns (above '2', say), something's probably gone wrong in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding the tables and alias them.

```
SELECT 
   leads.*, cardealers1.*, cardealers2.*, cardealers3* 
FROM leads 
LEFT JOIN cardealers as cardealers1
   ON leads.receiver_1 = cardealers1.cardealer_id 
LEFT JOIN cardealers as cardealers2
   ON leads.receiver_2 = cardealers2.cardealer_id
LEFT JOIN cardealers as cardealers3
   ON leads.receiver_3 = cardealers3.cardealer_id
WHERE 
   leads.receiver_1 = cardealers1.cardealer_id 
   AND leads.receiver_2 = cardealers2.cardealer_id 
   AND leads.receiver_3 = cardealers3.cardealer_id 
   AND cardealers.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."'
```

EDIT: it's best if you give an alias for the columns from each of the cardealers

Comment: Hi @Tah Tatsumoto 

Thanks for the quick response. 

It doesn't work right away.
I do the query as a result of a POST-request. 
Where $cardealer_id corresponds to the ID. 

In the last line of your code, it says:
cardealers.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."

1. Aren't there a AND missing in front of this?
2. Do I need to replicate this? like cardealers1.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."', cardealers2.cardealer_id = '". $cardealer_id ."' etc?